# Why are there no skill descriptions in the 5E players handbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills

I can't find a description of the cleric's medicine skill anywhere. Am I just not looking in the right place?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to RPG.SE. If you haven't already, you might want to check out the site tour and FAQ. It gives an overview of how we're different from other forums out there. =)

Comment: Hello and welcome. You are probably getting downvotes because questions that are trivially answered by the book count under the downvote criteria, which is "This question shows no research effort." But don't take it too hard, you got an answer after all...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Skill descriptions can be found starting on page 175 of the PHB under the heading **Using Each Ability.**

Comment: And a page before that under the heading Skills.

Comment: Shortest post I've seen get a Gold badge, wow!